# Modify array created with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, split

I’ve spent the day trying to figure this issue out. I can create an array from a DOM class easy enough.

The array returns `i.fa fa-diamond`, `i.fa fa-paper-plane` etc. The issue I’m trying to solve is removing the `i.` from the `fa fa-` strings. I’ve tried `.remove()`, `.splice()`, `filter`, `$map`, etc. methods without much luck. I’d like to remove the `i.` or find a simple way to create the array avoiding the `i.`.

Edit : I should have mentioned this is part of an assignment I understand there are easier ways of achieving this but I've been tasked to use jQuery.

```js
var obj = $('.card > .fa');
var cardsName = $.makeArray(obj);
console.log(cardsName);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="deck">
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card match">
    <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-cube"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card match">
    <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-bomb"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-bomb"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card open show">
    <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-cube"></i>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What are you trying to get? An array of `li`s? An array of strings of the unique classes (`fa-diamond`), or what?

Comment: The array I'm trying to get is ['fa fa-diamond', 'fa fa-paper-plane-o', 'fa fa-anchor', 'fa fa-bolt', 'fa fa-cube', 'fa fa-anchor', 'fa fa-leaf', 'fa fa-bicycle', 'fa fa-diamond', 'fa fa-bomb', 'fa fa-leaf', 'fa fa-bomb', 'fa fa-bolt', 'fa fa-bicycle', 'fa fa-paper-plane-o', 'fa fa-cube']. I'm getting ['i.fa fa-diamond', 'i.fa fa-paper-plane-o', 'i.fa fa-anchor', 'i.fa fa-bolt', 'i.fa fa-cube', 'i.fa fa-anchor', 'i.fa fa-leaf', 'i.fa fa-bicycle', 'i.fa fa-diamond', 'i.fa fa-bomb', 'i.fa fa-leaf', 'i.fa fa-bomb', 'i.fa fa-bolt', 'i.fa fa-bicycle', 'i.fa fa-paper-plane-o', 'i.fa fa-cube']

Comment: @grazed101 What you’re getting is `HTMLElement`s, not strings. An `HTMLElement` has a `className` property. It’s probably also interesting how you intend to use the resulting array. Why do you need an array of class names? If you want to select the elements corresponding to those classes, you have already solved that with your existing code.

Comment: @Xufox it's for a memory game assignment. I was able to just create an array in javascript which worked fine but I wanted to have a crack at doing it through DOM. If I update the HTML with new cards then the array will pick up any new cards that are created & shuffled. I'm still very new to this so not very clever yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the array of classes, you can use `map` and get class attr

```js
var obj = $('.card > .fa').map(function() {
  return $(this).attr('class');
}).get();

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="deck">
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card match">
    <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-cube"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card match">
    <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-bomb"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-bomb"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card open show">
    <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-cube"></i>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I appreciate it.

Comment: Happy to help @grazed101

Answer (score 4):

No need for a heavyweight library like jQuery, just select the elements and use `Array.from` to `map` to an array of their `className`s:

```js
const classes = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('.deck i'),
  i => i.className
);
console.log(classes);
```

```html
<ul class="deck">
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card match">
    <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-cube"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card match">
    <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-bomb"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-bomb"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card open show">
    <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-cube"></i>
  </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = document.querySelectorAll('.deck  i');
const classArr = [...arr].map(ele => ele.className);
console.log(classArr);
```

```html
<ul class="deck">
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card match">
    <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-cube"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card match">
    <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-bomb"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-bomb"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card open show">
    <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-cube"></i>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you could use a simpler approach:

```js
var arr=[];    
$('.fa').each(function(){
     arr.push ($(this).attr('class'));
});
console.log (arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="deck">
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card match">
    <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-cube"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card match">
    <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-bomb"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-bomb"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card open show">
    <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fa fa-cube"></i>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Well, he said: `The issue I’m trying to solve is removing the i. from the fa fa- strings` and I did. But yes, you're right, I forgot to make it an array. I changed my answer now.